# Calling javascript functions in another JS file without an HTML file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some generic functions written within a first js file.

**first.js**

```
function genFunc1(param1, param2) {
    //do  stuff
}

function genFunc2(param1, param2) {
    //do  other stuffs
}
```

I wanna re-use those functions in another file.

In my second js file, I wanna simply call them:

**second.js**

```
genFunc1("foo", 1);
genFunc2("bar", 3);
...
```

I have no HTML file which is running and I don't wanna use such solution because, in fact, my `senond.js` is compiled in another step.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Describe you functions in first file as a module. For node.js is :

```
module.exports = {
   yourFunctions:asMethods
}
```

And then require a module in your second file

```
var myModule = require('/pathToYour.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

This article goes in depth on how to export functions in Node.js - [Understanding Module Exports in Node.js](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/).

I just came across [this article](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c) as well which discusses Node.js modules vs. ES6. Below you can check out a snipper that shows how to export functions in both node.js and ES6... I think you'll find it's pretty straight forward once you get an understanding of it.

```
/** Node.js way */
// src/foobar.js
function foo() {
  return 'bar';
}
function bar() {
  return 'foo';
}
module.exports.foo = foo;
module.exports.bar = bar;
// In another file "src/app.js""
const {foo, bar} = require('foobar');
console.log(foo(), bar());

/** ES6 Way */
// src/foobar.js 
export function foo() {
  return 'bar';
}
export function bar() {
  return 'foo';
}
// In another file "src/app.js"
import { foo, bar } from './foobar'
console.log(foo());
console.log(bar());
```

Hope this helps!